# Playing a ding in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to be able to play a "ding" sound in Windows 8 (a kind of beep that fades out gently), similar to what is seen here: http://tonematrix.audiotool.com/

Is it possible to somehow play this given a frequency? Or can I download sound files for this anywhere?

I noticed how the `SoundPlayer` no longer works, so the old code I used in my desktop program won't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sound file of it, such as an mp3 or wav, use the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) control. There are a few ways of doing this. For example, set the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx) property to a URL (Uri class) or call [SetSource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br244338.aspx) then the [Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.play.aspx) method.

Windows 8 does not include an easy way to generate a tone or pitch (assuming you mean metro/Windows Store apps). If you can generate the bytes needed to play the sound, place them in a buffer, create an [IRandomAccessStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream.aspx) for it then pass it to SetSource. You can emulate the fade out by setting the [Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.volume.aspx) with a Timer.

It would be nice if there was a "fade out" audio effect that could be used with [SetAudioEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement.addaudioeffect) but Microsoft [does not provide any audio effects at this time](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/winappswithcsharp/thread/357e9fc8-7fa6-4790-b29f-6b25644a08c8).

Comment: Is there a better more performance-wise and always-the-same-sounding way of doing the fade-out than a timer? What if I have many dings playing over eachother at the same time?

Comment: The best performing way is to use a sound file that already contains the fade. If not, there may be a better way than using a timer with the Volume property but I do not know something off hand. As for playing multiple dings, you will need multiple MediaElement controls, one for each ding. Probably not the answers you are looking for. Sorry.